# Regarding the Halting problem and the human mind

Tags: artificial-intelligence, cognitive-sciences, self-cognition

The Halting problem (I think) is the problem of trying to find a general algorithm for determining if a specific program will halt within a computer system. It's been shown a general procedure for this doesn't exist (I think). Does this apply to the organisational abilities of the mind? Any information management system like the mind/brain has to orchestrate when certain programs are to 'run' or be changed and if it can't always tell when a program is going to halt how can the system organize itself??

Comment: The *Turing machine* is a mathematical *model* of computing, and also of human computing. To extrapolate that it is a *model* of human mind is a very very **big** extrapolation. Current "general purpose computers" are quite effective implementation of the mathematical concept of *universal Turing machine* (with obvious limitations regarding the tape ...) and they works quite well.

Comment: It's not simply that a general solution isn't known, but that it can't exist; the halting problem is "undecidable" (over TMs)

Comment: You should update this question with a more accurate description of the halting problem.

Comment: In Buddhist doctrine, which could be deemed an ancient discourse of the mind (and the psyche), there is what is called "saṃsāra", the never ending death-rebirth (or becoming-unbecoming) cycle of mental states — a potential starting point? There is also what I would call the "dependency graph of existence", called dependent origination (_paticcasamuppada_ or _pratityasamutpada_), its dual being nirvana (liberation from the discrete graph).  (freely disregard this comment as unscientific, it is merely and completely my personal opinion, afaik, and neither solid nor well structured)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The halting problem says nothing directly about minds.  It says something about recursive sets and recursively enumerable sets.  A *recursively enumerable* set is a set of integers that can be generated (enumerated) by a Turing machine.  (We can create a Turing machine that will print each member of the set on its tape.)

Turing's theorem is:

given any encoding of integers into computing machines, the set of integer pairs

K = { < *i*, *j* > | program *i* halts when run on input *j* }

is recursively enumerable while its complement

not(K) = { < *i*, *j* > | program *i* does *not* halt when run on input *j* }

is not.

It should not be surprising that there are many sets of integers (or of integer pairs) that are not recursively enumerable.  There are only countably many integers (and only countably many integer pairs), thus only countably many Turing machines encodable by the integers.  But the set of all sets of integers (the *power set* of the integers), is uncountably infinite.  So "most" sets of integers are not recursively enumerable.

Turing's proof is by diagonalization, and is similar to the [liar's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox).

Let's look at the set
doesntHaltOnItself = { *i* | program *i* does not halt when run on input *i* }

Can we construct a Turing machine, H, that halts and prints "accept" for all *i* in doesntHaltOnItself, and otherwise (if *i* halts when run on *i*) runs forever?  Suppose so.  Is H in doesntHaltOnItself?  Suppose H *is* in doesntHaltOnItself.  Then when H is run on input H it does not halt.  But for all *i* in doesntHaltOnItself H was supposed to halt and print "accept".  So H must not be in doesntHaltOnItself.  But that means that when H runs on itself it halts.  But when H is run on a program that halts on itself it is supposed to run forever.  Also a contradiction.  So our assumption that we could construct H is incorrect.  Note that doesntHaltOnItself is essentially a subset of not(K), so not(K) is not recursively enumerable.

Turing's theorem, like Gödel's theorem (and Cantor's diagonalization procedure), tells us something deep about the limits of logic, set theory and mathematics.

Whether Turing's theorem (or Gödel's theorem (or the cardinality of power sets)) tells us anything interesting about human minds depends on a whole other set of assumptions (like whether or not you believe that consciousness depends on the ability to enumerate sets that are not recursively enumerable.)

Your question was specifically about the connection between Turing's theorem and "self organization".  I see no connection between the ability to "self organize" and the ability to enumerate sets that aren't recursively enumerable.  It's not even apparent to me that a self organizing system needs to be able to enumerate all the recursively enumerable sets (and certainly not any of the non finite recursively enumerable sets.)

Comment: I've never heard that the proof shows that the set of programs that don't halt is _uncountably_ infinite. Where are you getting that from?

Comment: @senderle: :$  I was getting that from being wrong.  I've corrected my answer.  Thanks for pointing out my error!

Comment: Ah, yes -- and I like that you made the explicit point that there are an uncountable number of (countable) subsets of the integers -- that gave me a new insight into the role of diagonalization in the proof.

Comment: If the mind is really like a cognitive machine with strictly defined rules and definitions and it has the ability to self-organize would it need to schedule when certain processes or programs are to run and when previously running processes halt?

Comment: I suppose so.  It sounds like you are describing a computer operating system, like Linux.  The "halting problem" doesn't prohibit you from observing that a process has halted.  Nor does it prohibit you from terminating a process that is currently running (hasn't halted on its own.)  Nor, for that matter, does it prohibit you determining whether _some_ programs don't terminate.  Nor does it say that the programs that you can't determine whether or not they halt are required for any cognitive process.

Comment: Actually, assuming you believe that everyone (including yourself) will eventually die, then you _do_ know that every physical process involved in the human mind eventually halts.  So the halting problem is (as far as I can determine) irrelevant to the question of human cognition.

Comment: @user128932, Wandering Logic's comment above gives an excellent list of things that Turing's proof does _not_ prohibit. I'll add one more: it doesn't apply to an _inconsistent_ formal system. And the mind seems to operate in ways that are less rigorous than the kinds of formal systems that Turing was analyzing. Therefore the human mind may not be subject to the same restrictions -- not because it somehow "transcends" them, but because it doesn't necessarily give consistent results. (As we can see by the fact that people accept invalid "proofs" all the time!)

Comment: If the mind-brain is like a formal logic system as some people seem to imply ; a neurological mechanical neuronal-stimulus computing system where everything is subject to chemical and physical determinism then any neuro-mechanical 'programs' and their organization would be 'limited' by the halting problem. If the mind-brain is not like a formal logic or mechanical system , not like an inconsistent formal system ; it is more like a semi-consistent INFORMAL logic system.

Comment: A successful A.I. system probably would have the ability to reprogram itself ; that is , reprogram parts of itself , reprogram some or all of certain important programs or reprogram certain necessary functions all in such a way so as to not 'sabotage' it's important functions. So it should be able change various 'parts' of itself and still be self-sustaining. YET if a program system like an A.I system can reprogram itself it must be able to solve the 'halting' problem regarding 'itself'. It must be able to tell when a program it's going to change is going to 'halt'.